# WordPress Authors not showing with User Submitted Posts plugin

Tags: author

I'm using the User Submitted Post plugin to allow people to post to my blog. However when i run `<?php wp_list_authors(); ?>` I see none of the authors listed on the posts page in the dashboard. Are these not users? How can i list the authors that submitted all my posts through this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

**Unless those authors register (or created a user card by admin)

and log in in order to submit a post they are not users**

Also...  (in case they are logged in)
the form must record the current user
and add that to the data being submitted...

Additional information would require you
to share with us the name of your plugin.

Hope this clears things...
Sagive